# Contact Form 7 + Google reCAPTCHA - How do I set up server-side configuration?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, recaptcha, contacts

Thank you for reading my problem in advance. I am trying to incorporate Google's new reCAPTCHA (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/) into a Wordpress site that is using Contact Form 7. I have inserted the front-end code provided by Google:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the server-side integration configured. From what I can tell, I need to insert this code into my contact form HTML (see https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha#Part_2:_Installation):

```
<?php
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $publickey = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"; // you got this from the signup page
 echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);?>
```

When I do that on the Contact Form 7 backend, it just displays the text in between "< ?" and "? >". I'm also a little confused about the other steps and there are not many resources online about this new captcha.

Thanks again.

-Trent

Comment: If you're putting PHP into the "Form" section on the "Edit Contact Form" page, that's going to filter out any PHP code and you're seeing the result.  Are you sure Contact Form 7 supports google recaptcha?  You might need to go with a captcha that's supported out of the box, or post a question to the authors here http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7

Comment: Have you checked : https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-recaptcha/

Comment: @JoeT - I will go ahead and post there as well. I don't see why it wouldn't support the new standard through a little bit of integration. The demo Google gives should be able to work on any contact form.

Anand - The is the old standard of reCAPTCHA. I'm looking for a solution for the newer standard.

Comment: if you can edit the PHP yourself, then sure it will support it.  If not, then the plugin authors may need to provide a way to integrate the required code from google.  Whether they've done so is not apparent from the plugin settings page, it doesn't seem like it to me...